# how to cut the pattern from a multiple line string and store to the new variable?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, cut

I have a string variable

```
$var="-- this is a  --
      -- comment --
      hellow
      world"
```

i need to cut the string string into two parts such that there are two new string variable

```
$var1="-- this is a  --
      -- comment --"

$var2="hellow
       world"
```

i need the new line as it is in the $var1 $var2

what i have tried

```
var2=$(echo $var | sed 's/^--.*--//g')
```

i am not able to store the pattern in $var1 that it is deleting .

Note : hyphen is important and new line is important to maintain .
have tried bash string manipulation but it doesn't worked

Comment: Does $var contain new lines or not ? Your sample looks like 4 lines.

Comment: It does, at least last time he asked almost the same question (now seems deleted) `echo "$var"` shows them.

Comment: @JamesBrown If $var contains new lines , then my solution seems valid....

Comment: Looks good to me. Now we wait for the OP to approve or disapprove the solution. I'll just leave these here: `echo "${var##*--}"` and `echo "${var%--*}"--` The former echoes one extra newline, anyone know how to remove that?

Comment: @JamesBrown use `printf` or `echo -n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `grep`

For `var1`

```
 grep  '\-\-.*\-\-'
```

For `var2`

```
 grep -v '\-\-.*\-\-'
```

As suggest by @123, we don't need escaping, if we use `--` in grep command.

So you can use this as well

For `var1`

```
 grep  -- '--.*--'
```

For `var2`

```
 grep -v '--.*--'
```

Comment: NP. Please accept the answer so the question could be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you escaping `-`'s ?

Comment: I tried it on `Linux 3.10.0-327.36.2.el7.x86_64` and it didn't work there without escape.

Comment: You need to put `--` before the string, or it will treat it like a flag. i.e `grep -- '--.*--'` and `grep -v -- '--.*--'`

Comment: Perfect. No need to put escape if using `--` before the string. Editing the answer to put this too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `$var` as presented in your question seems to contain new lines,making your `$var` to consist of actually 4 different lines. In that case you can split the lines like:

```
$ var1=$(sed -n '1,2p' <<<"$var")
$ var2=$(sed -n '3,4p' <<<"$var")
```

$var1 gets the lines 1 and 2 of $var (or from a file if you like)
$var2 gets the lines 3 and 4 of $var (or from a file if you like)

Comment: won't work. The Op's `$var` contains `-- this is a -- -- comment -- hellow world`(without newlines) after asignment (in that form he posted)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Without newlines? But data are presented with new lines in question! Oh god.